# Checking geometry type of vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How do I check the geometry type of a vector layer in QGIS?

I would like to know whether a layer uses Polygons or MultiPolygons or Points, but I can't see anything in the Properties dialog that tells me.

Comment: There is no section titled _"Geometry type of the features in this layer"_ in `Layer Properties > Metadata > Properties`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Properties >> Metadata >> Properties Section has things like "Storage Type" (eg Shapefile) and:

```
Geometry type of the features in this layer
Line (WKB type: "LineString")
```

I don't know if any distinction is made between Polygons and Multipolygons here though.

Comment: It doesn't differentiate between line and multiline.

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS 3.18 Zürich you can access this information by clicking on the layer and then `Properties >> Information`. This information is generally available, but must be given by the provider.
[image]